# Does ExoPlayer Expose a Way to Tell Sliding vs. Complete Live Playlists

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using ExoPlayer 2.6.1 to play live HLS, and have the need to be able to tell if the HLS playlist is a sliding window or a complete playlist (that is ever growing). I want to display different player controls based on which type of playlist is being used, and I do not have access to that metadata. So I was curious if it was possible to get that information from the ExoPlayer itself.

I thought that I could be able to use the [Timeline as described here](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Timeline.html#live-limited), but I cannot seem to be able to tell the difference.

Answer (score 2):

HLS playlist can be of three different types: live (default), event or vod ([spec](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AboutHTTPLiveStreaming/about/about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013978-CH3-SW9)). For event or vod the type is set in the playlist either with

```
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
```

or

```
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
```

According to the [spec](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AboutHTTPLiveStreaming/about/about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013978-CH3-SW9) the EVENT type is what you are calling Complete Live Playlist:

> An event playlist, shown in Listing 2, has the same format as the live
>   media playlist above, with the exception of an extra line:
>    #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT. That designation alerts media player that this playlist will behave differently than a live media playlist.
>   Event playlists maintain the references to older media while gaining
>   new references.

With ExoPlayer you can register a listener to listen for timeline changes. The callback has a manifest parameter you can consult:

```
player.addListener(new Player.DefaultEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {
    if (manifest != null) {
      switch (((HlsManifest)manifest).mediaPlaylist.playlistType) {
        case HlsMediaPlaylist.PLAYLIST_TYPE_VOD:
          Log.d("TAG", "playlist type VOD");
          break;
        case HlsMediaPlaylist.PLAYLIST_TYPE_EVENT:
          Log.d("TAG", "playlist type EVENT");
          break;
        default:
          Log.d("TAG", "playlist type LIVE");
          break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I am not sure that I am following what I can key off of to tell if it is a sliding vs. a complete playlist. Can you elaborate on how to use the `positionInWindowMs` value to determine it?

Comment: I changed the answer to a HLS specific solution. This seems easier and more reliable.